# How to connect .so (C code) to a R package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a trouble to create a R package.

I have a compiled C code named "a.so", where "void b(...)" and "void c(...)" were defined in a.so. In R code, `dyn.load(a.so)` works well to use `.C("b",...)` and `.C("c",...)`.

To create a R package, I saved a.so file to `src` folder and wrote `useDynLib(a)` in `NAMESPACE` file. However, it gave error messages as below. Could you help me how to handle it? I used RStudio on Ubuntu. (I am not sure why `library.dynam` was shown, since I did not use it).

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 

  shared object ‘a.so’ not found

Error: loading failed

Execution halted

ERROR: loading failed
```

Comment: Just create a package -- which I would do via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` when I want to add C++ code -- and add your code in `src/`.  One can do it manually to, but this may be easier for you.

Comment: It seems that .c (and .o) file should be also included in the src folder. Is my understanding correct?